# ORA-30926: unable to get stable rowset in source tables

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I try to perform a merge, however, it does not allow me, I already add DISTINCT, purge the fields for update and in the USING function they are unique fields, they are not repeated each one has different information, it is worth mentioning that to the table that I want to insert or update data already exist.

```
MERGE INTO   B69_TBL_ALERTA_CONCENTRADO concentrado
    USING  (SELECT  DISTINCT 
                    archivo.id_archivo,archivo.rfc, archivo.nombre_contribuyente , archivo.situacion_contribuyente ,
                    archivo.oficio_global, archivo.publicacion_presuntos , archivo.publicacion_definitivos
    FROM B69_CAT_ALERTA_ARCHIVO archivo
    INNER JOIN  TBL_TRANSACCIONES txn   
       ON txn.titular = archivo.nombre_contribuyente)v_using    
    ON (concentrado.nombre_contribuyente = v_using.nombre_contribuyente)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
concentrado.id_archivo = v_using.id_archivo,
concentrado.snapshot_date = DATE '2021-06-16',
concentrado.rfc = v_using.rfc,
concentrado.situacion_contribuyente = v_using.situacion_contribuyente,
concentrado.oficio_global = v_using.oficio_global,
concentrado.publicacion_presuntos = v_using.publicacion_presuntos,
concentrado.publicacion_definitivos = v_using.publicacion_definitivos,
concentrado.last_update = CURRENT_DATE,
concentrado.id_alertatipo = 2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (concentrado.id_concentrado,concentrado.id_archivo,concentrado.snapshot_date,concentrado.rfc,concentrado.nombre_contribuyente,
        concentrado.situacion_contribuyente,concentrado.oficio_global,concentrado.publicacion_presuntos,
        concentrado.publicacion_definitivos,concentrado.baja_logica,concentrado.last_update,concentrado.id_alertatipo)
VALUES (b69id_gralaut.nextval,v_using.id_archivo,DATE '2021-06-16',v_using.rfc,v_using.nombre_contribuyente,
        v_using.situacion_contribuyente,v_using.oficio_global,v_using.publicacion_presuntos,
        v_using.publicacion_definitivos,'0',CURRENT_DATE,'2');
        
COMMIT;        
END STP_69B_ALERTA_EXTERNA;
```

And I get the following error:

```
Connecting to the Alerts database.
ORA-30926: unable to get stable rowset in source tables
ORA-06512: in "CDO_ALERTAS.STP_69B_ALERTA_EXTERNA", line 4
ORA-06512: online 2
The process is over.
Disconnecting from the Alerts database.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem - the `using` subquery produces duplicated rows in the key `nombre_contribuyente`

Check with

```
with v_using as (SELECT  DISTINCT 
                    archivo.id_archivo,archivo.rfc, archivo.nombre_contribuyente , archivo.situacion_contribuyente ,
                    archivo.oficio_global, archivo.publicacion_presuntos , archivo.publicacion_definitivos
    FROM B69_CAT_ALERTA_ARCHIVO archivo
    INNER JOIN  TBL_TRANSACCIONES txn   
       ON txn.titular = archivo.nombre_contribuyente)
select nombre_contribuyente, count(*)
from v_using
group by nombre_contribuyente
order by 2 desc;
```

On the top of the result you see the keys that have count > 1

You must reformulated the `using` subquery such that the join key of merge is unique - `Distinct` is not enough, you must use e.g. `GROUP BY` on the key.

Comment: ok, I'll check and try to remove the duplicates.